# Registration message over TCP

Tags: tcp, sip, registration

I have implemented SIP calls over TCP.
Now I intend to extrapolate it to REGISTRATION over TCP.

I have a reference PCAP with the following flow:

**Logic for Sequence number and Acknowledgement number for initial registration:**

A------------------------------------B      Seq -         Ack   -           Size

```
           REGISTER
```

----------------------------------→         1    -            1      -         709

```
        100 Giving a Try
```

<----------------------------------         1            -     710          -   358

```
        401 Unauthorized
```

<----------------------------------         359   -            710      -     459

```
          REGISTER
```

----------------------------------→         710      -        818   -          931

```
        100 Giving a Try
```

<----------------------------------         818      -         1641     -      358

```
       200OK
```

<----------------------------------         1176   -            1641    -       450

**sequence number of current leg= (sequence number of previous leg in same direction+window size of previous leg in same direction**.)

**Ack number of current leg     =(Ack number of previous leg)                                                                                          {if current leg is in same direction as previous one}**

**=(sequence number of previous leg)+(window size of previous leg )                              {else}**

I am trying to understand the following:

1. Should the refresh instance be part of the same TCP stream?
   Which means should the Src and dest IP addresses and Src and Dest Port addresses of the refresh instance be the same as the initial registration?
2. What logic should be applied to the Seq and Ack numbers?
   Should they be in continuation to the previous messages (initial registration attempt) or should these values be as if a new instance is being generated between the given devices?

PS: I am working on a tool that generates calls among devices, so src and dest message code is within my realm.

Comment: It is really unclear to me what you mean. Could it be you are mixing up SIP sequence numbers and TCP sequence numbers? Those are not related. I think you can find answers to your registration questions in RFC 3261.

Comment: I am talking about TCP header parameter sequence number and acknowledgement number strictly. I mean to ask that when a refresh instance is sent from the source to the destination within the expires interval, should the refresh instance be framed such that it is the part of the same TCP stream as the original registration? or should it consist of seq=1 and ack=1 (i.e new TCP stream altogether)?

Comment: SIP registrations are independent of the used transport protocol. If you want to update an existing SIP registration that was established over a TCP connection you can send the registration update request over the same TCP connection, another TCP connection or even via UDP. As long as the request is sent to the same registrar the update request will be treated as such. More information in RFC 5626.

Comment: Glad I could help. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SIP registrations are independent of the used transport protocol. If you want to update an existing SIP registration that was established over a TCP connection you can send the registration update request over the same TCP connection, another TCP connection or even via UDP. As long as the request is sent to the same registrar the update request will be treated as such.

More information on the use of seq numbers and SIP registration (update) in the  [Registration section of RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-10).
More information SIP registration paths and the use of (different) transport protocols in RFC 5626.